# Arduino: Attach an interrupt to one of the higher pin numbers?

Tags: arduino

I have an [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560). Is is possible to attach an interrupt on the higher pin numbers, for instance, D20 to D25? I tried [PcInt](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PcInt), but it doesn't work with the higher pin numbers for some reason.

I have a custom board and it's using these pins, so my hands are tied in terms of what pins to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pin mapping of the Mega2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560) says that pins 20-25 aren't candidates for PCINTs (but 20 and 21 would have INTs). So the layout of the board makes it simply incompatible for this Arduino.